# Creating a stack of annual images

Tags: google-earth-engine, shape-area, calculate-geometry

I am working with the tropical moist forest dataset (https://forobs.jrc.ec.europa.eu/TMF/data.php#downloads) and I have a script where I can calculate the areas for a specific year based on landcover classes for a feature collection (https://code.earthengine.google.com/0c80ca868e67255c4da9e658575cc531).

As my script is currently written, I have to run each year separately (lines 73-104; see code snippet below) and export a separate CSV file for each year.

```
var AnnualChangesYear1=TMF_AnnualChanges.select('Dec1990').clip(community_lands); // clipped to annual layers

//---------START f(x) to calculate area by class over a feature

var calculateClassArea = function(feature) {
    var areas = ee.Image.pixelArea().addBands(AnnualChangesYear1)
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
      groupField: 1,
      groupName: 'class',
    }),
    geometry: feature.geometry(),
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e10
    })
 
    var classAreas = ee.List(areas.get('groups'))
    var classAreaLists = classAreas.map(function(item) {
      var areaDict = ee.Dictionary(item)
      var classNumber = ee.Number(
        areaDict.get('class')).format()
      var area = ee.Number(
        areaDict.get('sum')).divide(10000).round()
      return ee.List([classNumber, area])
    })
 
    var result = ee.Dictionary(classAreaLists.flatten())
    var district = feature.get('Name')
    return ee.Feature(
      feature.geometry(),
      result.set('district', district))
}
```

How can I create a stack of the annual years that I can iterate over for my feature collection where my CSV export has each year as a column (31 years) and each row is a feature from my feature collection?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that creating an annual changes list and mapping it with a function as follows. This function has code lines for including "annualChanges" (32 years; not 31) as property for visualizing it in corresponding CSV file.

```
var annualChanges = ['Dec1990', 'Dec1991', 'Dec1992', 'Dec1993', 'Dec1994',
                     'Dec1995', 'Dec1996', 'Dec1997', 'Dec1998', 'Dec1999',
                     'Dec2000', 'Dec2001', 'Dec2002', 'Dec2003', 'Dec2004',
                     'Dec2005', 'Dec2006', 'Dec2007', 'Dec2008', 'Dec2009',
                     'Dec2010', 'Dec2011', 'Dec2012', 'Dec2013', 'Dec2014',
                     'Dec2015', 'Dec2016', 'Dec2017', 'Dec2018', 'Dec2019',
                     'Dec2020', 'Dec2021'];

var communityLandsYears = annualChanges.map(function (annualChanges) {

  var scale = TMF_AnnualChanges.select(annualChanges).projection().nominalScale(); 

  //print('Resolution (meters): ', scale); // Scale = 98.95065848192033
  //publications = 0.09 ha (30 x 30 m pixel)??

  AnnualChangesYear1=TMF_AnnualChanges.select(annualChanges);

  Map.addLayer(AnnualChangesYear1.updateMask(AnnualChangesYear1),{
    'min': 1,
    'max': 6,
    'palette': PALETTEAnnualChanges
  }, "JRC - Annual Changes - one year – v1 " + annualChanges, false);


  //=================================================================================================
  //=================================================================================================

  // PART 2:  calculate annual area for each class: 1= undisturbed TMF; 
  // 2=degraded TMF; 3=deforested TMF; 4= forest regrowth; 5= permanent/season water; 6 = other land cover

  var AnnualChangesYear1 = TMF_AnnualChanges.select(annualChanges).clip(community_lands); // clipped to annual layers

  //---------START f(x) to calculate area by class over a feature

  var calculateClassArea = function(feature) {
    var areas = ee.Image.pixelArea().addBands(AnnualChangesYear1)
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
      groupField: 1,
      groupName: 'class',
    }),
    geometry: feature.geometry(),
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e10
    });
 
    var classAreas = ee.List(areas.get('groups'));
    var classAreaLists = classAreas.map(function(item) {
      var areaDict = ee.Dictionary(item);
      var classNumber = ee.Number(
        areaDict.get('class')).format();
      var area = ee.Number(
        areaDict.get('sum')).divide(10000).round();
      return ee.List([classNumber, area]);
    });
 
    var result = ee.Dictionary(classAreaLists.flatten());
    var district = feature.get('Name');
    return ee.Feature(
      feature.geometry(),
      result.set('district', district));
  };

  //--------- END f(x)

  var districtAreas = community_lands.map(calculateClassArea); // apply over features

  districtAreas = districtAreas.map(function (feat) {
  
    return feat.set("annualChanges", annualChanges);
  
  });

  return districtAreas;

});

//print(ee.List(communityLandsYears));

var communityLandsYears = ee.List(communityLandsYears).map(function (ele) {
  
  return ee.List(ee.FeatureCollection(ele)
    .toList(ee.FeatureCollection(ele).size())).flatten();
  
}).flatten();
```

After running [complete code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/d799b33ef5feb3d612851ba6ff355c11) in GEE code editor and also running the task, I got following CSV file for all years as follows:

[image]

Picture only shows a sample (1990-1997) of all years (1990-2021). In CSV file was deleted geom column for a better visualization.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.